# No Java code completion in VSCode in gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup my VSCode to get proper code completion in this project: https://github.com/structurizr/java-extensions

I have the Java Extension Pack installed in my VSCode.

But it is not even recognized as a Java project. If I add every single "src" folder via "Add folder to java source path" the Java imports are recognized but the code completion is still not working.

Any hints on what is wrong or what I need to configure in my VSCode to make it work?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried installing IntelliCode extension?

Comment: Did you install Vs Code Coding Pack for Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this is a Gradle Project, In addition to Java Extension Pack, you should install [Gradle Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=naco-siren.gradle-language).

Then reopen the project in VS Code, Gradle extension will download the required files to be able to build and compile the project. After all downloads finished, you can edit your project and auto-completion would work as normal:

[image]

Comment: After chanfing my JDK to a 1.8 and tweaking some proxy related settings it is working now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad your question had been solved. Happy Coding :)